# How to insert a datatable into SQL Server database using Uipath database activitvities?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, uipath

I have a datatable `DT` with 25 columns. I want to insert that data from `DT` into a SQL Server table `SQDT` with the same columns. I'm using an `INSERT` query for now.

Is there a better way to approach this problem instead of using `INSERT` on each record? Can I bulk insert into the database using a stored procedure or some other efficient way? It takes a lot of time to insert as `DT` has 130000 tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way. You need to create Type in SQL server with the same definition as your Datatable.

Here you can `User-Defined TableType`

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
)
```

Define Parameter in SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTable]
    @myTable MyTable readonly
AS
BEGIN
    insert into [dbo].Records select * from @myTable 
END
```

and send your `DataTable` as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlBulkCopy in-build for C#.
SqlBulk Copy can be used for bulk inserts with batches which worked efficiently for me
https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-fast-inserts/